# CSS Emulate position:sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

My document structure:

```
<div id="section">
      <div class="subSection">
         <h2></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="subSection">
          <div></div>
      </div>
      <div id="controlBox">
          <h2></h2>
          <form></form>
      </div>
</div>
```

I need to emulate the fabled position:sticky (which I can't get to work, or really find much documentation on) on the #controlBox. Any way to do this with JS or CSS?

Comment: So what should it look like? There is a contradiction in your question.

Comment: What's the contradiction? I will reword - I need to have a box (#controlBox) that has the same behaviour as "position:fixed" (e.g scrolls with the page) in the section div, but also needs to be positioned below the two subsections

Comment: `position:fixed` means that it does not scroll with the page. It stays on its screen position when you scroll.

Comment: Ok, done some research. Trying to emulate position:sticky. Question update to reflect this really.

Comment: Makes more sense :) But: `controlBox` is the last element. `sticky` only makes sense if there is content after it. Anyway: pure CSS currently only works on Safari and it's vendor prefixed: `position: -webkit-sticky`.

Comment: @JoshDredge Duude, look at this link: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit ... the part where it says "Old approach: Scroll Events", but be warned, it's going to slow down your website. A lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a purely CSS solution, but jQuery might be able to solve this problem.

Pseudo code:

```
// Calculate height of screen
// Choose what percentage of that both subSections take up
// Remaining percentage is the height of the controlBox
```

So it might look a little bit like this in jQuery:

```
// this returns the value of the browser's window's height in pixels
$height = $(window).height();

// this is considering that both subsections are next to each other (they take up 80% of the height)
$subsectionHeight = $height * 0.8;
```

Or, if the subsections are on top of each other, and they take up 80% of the height in total:

```
$subsectionHeight = $height * 0.4;

// controlBox takes up 20% of height of window
$controlboxHeight = $height * 0.2; 

// then you can assign the heights to each element
$('.subSection').css("height", "$subsectionHeight");
$('#controlBox').css("height", "$controlboxHeight");
```

I understand that you prefer pure CSS, but I find that jQuery is of great use at times.

If you do not know jQuery or are having trouble understanding jQuery, I recommend signing up for [Codecademy's jQuery course](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery).

Comment: and if you want your controlBox to be always at the bottom of the window, just set it's margin-bottom to 0. Understand that an element that has position:fixed is taken out of the DOM flow, so it doesn't know where everything else is. To solve overlapping problems, I think you have to use jQuery and crunch some numbers. Did I cover everything?

Comment: I avoid jQuery because it adds waaaay to much footprint and I need this site in particular to be lightweight.

I can easily convert your solution to normal JS though and unless someone else comes up with something better, that looks like the way to do things